# unobtrusive javascript without function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

if you have

```
<div id="data" onclick="handleData(1)">Datum 1</div>
```

and you want to late bind instead:

```
<div id="data">Datum 1</div>
<script>
    $("#data").click(function() {
        handleData(1);
    })
</script>
```

How do you pass that parameter 1? do you have to do something like this:

```
<div id="data" data="1">Datum 1</div>
<script>
    $("#data").click(function() {
        handleData($(this).attr("data"););
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just put the figure 1 directly into the parentheses in the function? Are you anticipating that div#data might want to call the function with a different argument in another scenario?

Comment: I could but inline javascript isn't really unobtrusive. if I had several Datums in a table, I'd want to bind the clicks in a bottom script after document complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're using jQuery.

If so, I'd take advantage of jQuery's support for the HTML5 `data-` attribute using the [`data()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method . It will in all browsers.

```
<div id="data" data-number="1">Datum 1</div>
<script>
    $("#data").click(function() {
        handleData($(this).data("number"));
    })
</script>
```

Notice that I changed the attribute to `data-number`, and accessed it with `.data("number")`. This requires `jQuery 1.4.3` or later.

**From the docs:**

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that all data attributes must be lower case in the markup (tested in Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

Your last approach is almost correct. You should use the `data` attribute as a prefix in the form of `data-someproperty`. Then you might access it through `$(this).data("someproperty")` or `$(this).attr("data-someproperty")`.

**Edit:** Read about: [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's more than one data element, yes, you'll have to pass that parameter some other way.  It doesn't have to be in the HTML though:

```
<div class="data">one</div>
<div class="data">two</div>
<div class="data">three</div>

<script>
    $('.data').each(function(ix){$(this).click(function(){handleData(ix)})});
</script>
```

This is a bit of an abuse of document-ordering, but it's pretty unobtrusive.